# Easiest way to create a Hash of Arrays (or equivalent) in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, hash

I am looking to create a Hash of Arrays (or some equivalent structure) that allows me to collect an unknown set of properties (keyed by name) and have each property store an array of things that claimed they have said property.

```
const currentProperties = currentObject.getProperties(); 
// we can assume getProperties correctly returns an array of valid properties

currentProperties.forEach( (v) => {  
  HoA[ v ].push( currentObject );  
});
```

I want to be able to do something like the above to populate the Hash of Arrays - but how to I actually properly initialize it/do all of the TypeScript stuff?    Currently I've been getting by using an enum to manually specify the possible properties that could show up, but I want to adapt it out to a structure that doesn't need to have a property list ahead of time, and can just take whatever shows up as a key.

As noted above, I understand how to solve a version of this problem if I manually specify the expected types of properties to be seen and use a bunch of

```
if (currentProperties.includes(Properties.exampleOne)) {
  this.exampleGroupOne.push(currentObject);
}
```

but I want to be able to have this work with no prior knowledge of what values of properties exist.

EDIT: some clarification on what I am asking for -

The goal is to have a bunch of objects that have a getProperties() method that returns an array of zero or more attributes. I want to have a data structure that, for each attribute that exists, ends up with an array of the objects that reported that attribute. That is easy when I know the possible attributes ahead of time, but in this case, I won't. For actually acting on the attributes, I'll need a loop that is the attributes on the outer layer [the hash] and the relevant objects on the inner layer [the array]. (This is why I'm assuming HoA)

EDIT #2:

```
class Alice {

    myProps(): string[] {
        return ["Apple"];
    }
}

class Bob {

    myProps(): string[] {
        return ["Banana"];
    }
}

class Charlie {

    myProps(): string[] {
        return ["Apple", "Banana"];
    }
}

const FruitBasket:{ [prop: string]: string} = {}

const myAlice = new Alice();
const myBob = new Bob();
const myCharlie = new Charlie();

const Objects = [myAlice, myBob, myCharlie];

for (const currentObject of Objects) {
    const fruits = currentObject.myProps();
    fruits.forEach( (v) => { FruitBasket[v].push(currentObject);});
}
```

I think this is almost what I want - I am getting an error that push does not exist on type string, but at this point I think I'm just missing something basic because I've been staring at this too long.

EDIT #3:

```
abstract class JustSomeGuy {
    myProps(): string[] {
        return [];
    }
    myName(): string {
        return '';
    }
}

class Alice extends JustSomeGuy {

    myProps(): string[] {
        return ["Apple"];
    }
    myName(): string {
        return 'Alice';
    }
}

class Bob extends JustSomeGuy {

    myProps(): string[] {
        return ["Banana"];
    }
    myName(): string {
        return 'Bob';
    }
}

class Charlie extends JustSomeGuy {

    myProps(): string[] {
        return ["Apple", "Banana"];
    }
    myName(): string {
        return 'Charlie';
    }
}

const FruitBasket:{ [prop: string]: JustSomeGuy[]} = {}

const myAlice = new Alice();
const myBob = new Bob();
const myCharlie = new Charlie();

const Objects = [myAlice, myBob, myCharlie];

for (const currentObject of Objects) {
    const fruits = currentObject.myProps();
    fruits.forEach( (v) => { (FruitBasket[v] ??= []).push(currentObject);});
}

for (let key in FruitBasket){
    let value = FruitBasket[key];
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
        console.log("In key: " + key + " the ith element [i = " + i + "] is: " + value[i].myName() );
    }
}
```

I believe that this is what I want. Marking this as resolved.

Comment: I see several questions here and not exactly sure which to address. To get the list of properties for an object, that's simply `Object.keys(myObj)`. As for the TypeScript stuff, I could give you general direction but it's unclear exactly how you want it used. Why do you want numerous object keys mapped to the same `currentObject` object.. seems like a waste of memory. Can you give us more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: To type an object with non-expicit property names, you can do it like so `const myObj: { [prop: string]: MyObjValueType } = {};`. If you know it's a key of another object, you can say `const myObj: { [prop: keyof MyObj]: MyObjValueType } = {};`

Comment: Sure - the goal is to have a bunch of objects that have a getProperties() method that returns an array of zero or more attributes. I want to have a data structure that, for each attribute that exists, ends up with an array of the objects that reported that attribute. That is easy when I know the possible attributes ahead of time, but in this case, I won't. For actually acting on the attributes, I'll need a loop that is the attributes on the outer layer [the hash] and the relevant objects on the inner layer [the array]. (This is why I'm assuming HoA)

Comment: So it sounds like the only thing you need is to have an object with generic property names - see my previous comment and let me know if that is what you're looking for

Comment: If you're supplying objects with a  `getProperties()` method, could you show a [mre] of that?  Generally speaking you'd just use `Object.keys(obj)` to get the property names, so if you think you need a `getProperties()` method I'm curious about what it actually does.  Using `Object.keys()` gives you [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYRe3w).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply so that I'm notified)

Comment: @mrhodges

I slightly changed the terminology, but I tinkered up a fruit-based example (edit #2) that is what I am trying to do, and I think it almost works

Comment: I think the only thing wrong with your fruit-based example is that it should be `const FruitBasket:{ [prop: string]: Array<Alice | Bob | Charlie>} = {}`. If you have a ton of different classes that it *could* be, you'd have to handle it generically or create some kind of base class that those extend

Comment: Yeah, I tried a version where Alice Bob and Charlie all extended a class called JustSomeGuy and had FruitBasket expect that, and that worked great, and can be adapted fairly easily to my actual use case. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the types of the data structures that you described:

```ts
type ObjWithProps = {
  getProperties (): string[];
};

type PropertyHolders = {
  [key: string]: ObjWithProps[] | undefined;
};
// Could also be written using built-in type utilities like this:
// type PropertyHolders = Partial<Record<string, string[]>>;
```

- The type `ObjWithProps` has a method which returns an array of `string` elements.
- The type `PropertyHolders` is an object type that is indexed by `string` values (keys), and each value type is an array of `ObjWithProps` (if it exists, or `undefined` if it doesn't) — no object has a value at every possible key.

Next, let's replicate the data structures you showed in your example:

```ts
const HoA: PropertyHolders = {};

const currentObject: ObjWithProps = {
  getProperties () {
    return ['p1', 'p2', 'p3' /* etc. */];
  }
};

const currentProperties = currentObject.getProperties();
```

In the code above, the `currentObject` has some arbitrary properties (`p1`, `p2`, `p3`). This is just to have [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) data. Your own implementation will likely be different, but the types are the same.

Finally, let's look at the part where you assign the values to the hash map:

```ts
currentProperties.forEach((v) => {
  HoA[v].push(currentObject); /*
  ~~~~~~
  Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532) */
});
```

You can see that there's a compiler error where you try to access the array at the key `v`. Because you aren't sure that the array exists (no object has a value at every key), trying to invoke a `push` method on `undefined` would throw a runtime error. TypeScript is trying to help you prevent that case.

Instead, you can use the [nullish coalescing assignment operator (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) to ensure that the array is created (if it doesn't already exist) before pushing in a new value. This is what that refactor would look like:

```ts
currentProperties.forEach((v) => {
  (HoA[v] ??= []).push(currentObject); // ok
});
```

[Full code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwOoEtgAsAKAnA9mAZygF4oBvAKCigHMJgd8JtgUIiAKASgC4oDg2FADsaAbQC6AbgoBfGRVCQojSCxAAJXABsAJsyKlK1MQGsIIPgKGiJfeMjRY8hSVAA+UAK7D9AMxEIXRl5CgB6MKgAYVwvPSgAQ20CXCg4aAB3IWBgCGFvAhEaNK8UbWAAWhEoJWgvVm00NiJG8xr0FAIecMjalRdmUC09AxIVBJYUJIAeACUIAGNcbF1p6yKAGn5BIskAPj2FJeEBKC0AQT5VQc0dfWxDclCKY9OFr2xsPOAHReB7RCoDCqR7GWj0a6TdhQbjkKjUKBfYAffJiADkYAAjGithiAEw4qAYgDMaKgYQAVFB6AsAHRQClhaTw2RyI64E7AKDvT7fSGsaGkHlfYQ-RB-Wl0BgDKEEbhHD4i6VMWW0vzLACiCQW6A4HAAblwSHs4dQOBcxPqJFAAPw20iSLi0sBeAi64XfX4LYBcKTkyK4UxyX0UIA)

---

Utility types references:

- [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)
- [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)